# Automatically shorten URLs on website with other domain name that I own

Tags: 7, uri

Yesterday I purchased the domain stps.me to be able to shorten URLs for my other website setups.co.

I found two modules, [Shorten URLs](http://drupal.org/project/shorten) and [ShURLy](http://drupal.org/project/shurly), that were able to shorten URLs.

However, I can't find the option to use my own domain name, and therefore I'm asking you for help.

I know there's a free tool to make your own URL shortening service called [Yourls](http://yourls.org/), but I can't figure out how to implement this to Drupal to automatically shorten and display a URL when I upload new nodes.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the "use my own domain name" part. You want yoursite.com/shorturl? You would use Pathauto for that.

Comment: [ShortURL](http://drupal.org/project/shorturl) maybe?

Comment: @beth I want to make short URLs like "stps.me/xRgD" for the URL "setups.co/node/1" as an example.

Comment: @Clive That module is only available for Drupal 6, I use 7.

Comment: There's very little to it though, would be easy to take the shortening logic out and put it in a small custom module

Comment: @Clive I'm sure that's possible, with the right skills, that I unfortunately don't have :/ They've tried to port it to D7 [here](http://drupal.org/node/1033046) but it doesn't seem to work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this module, [Yourls](http://drupal.org/project/yourls), that works exactly like I described above.